# Bottom of map fragment hidden under cardview

Tags: android, android-fragments

How can I get the map fragment I have in the first image to end where the card view starts, similar to how Strava does it in the second image.

[image: First Image]

[image: Second Image]

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<fragment
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="470dp"
tools:context="com.example.donal.navdrawer.Activities.MapsActivity"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/maps_toolbar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    />

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:elevation="4dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Use MapView instead of MapFragment and build layout you want.

Comment: You can use MapView instead of MapFragment Check this link it will help
[https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define the layout_height of the card view, you can set the fragment height to 0dp and weight to 1. This will make sure the fragment will take all the available space left.

Comment: @Donal harringtonno problem